# Modifying a field in serializers.ModelSerializer Class imported from an external library

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override/modify a `class XXXSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)` object defined in an external library that I am including in the `installed_apps` configuration of my `settings.py`.

```
    from rest_framework import serializers
    class XXXSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        username = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())])
        email = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all())],default='')
        class Meta:
            model = User
            exclude = [
                'is_superuser', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'content_type', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'account_id',
            ]
```

As shown above, the email is required to be unique in their definition. However, I do not want to require it to be unique. **My question is therefore, what is the best way to override this field?**

### Some thoughts/attempts:

1. Copy the entire library directly into my project, and take out the validator there. I think this would definitely work but may not be an optimal solution?
2. Somehow override it by defining another `YYYSerializer` with my desired property, and use

   `import external_library`

   `sys.module['external_library.XXXSerializer'] = YYYSerializer.`

   However, I'm not exactly sure about 1. where to put this piece of code, 2. the proper syntax, 3. whether this would even work in an ideal situation. When I put it in `settings.py` or some `__init__` files, it returns `Apps aren't loaded yet` error - probably because the external_library hasn't been loaded yet.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

---

Edit to make request clearer:
Want to redefine the field of `class XXXSerializer` outside of the library `XXXSerializer` is residing in. For example, it would be ideal if I could define something like:

```
class XXXSerializer(external_library.XXXSerializer):
        email = serializers.CharField(default='')
```

in hope to override this particular `email` field for that class, by executing some code in my main apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to `override/remove` the **unique email constraint**. First of all, it's a parameter passing to the respective class, so the validation condition can be removed by simply removing the parameter, as below

```
email = serializers.CharField(default='')
```

By default  `validators` parameter of `CharField()` class is `None`

**Override `CharField()` class**

to override `CharField()` class, do as below

```
class SubCharFieldClass(serializers.CharField):
    #do some overriding process

class MySerializerClass(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email = SubCharFieldClass()
    # other fields
```

**UPDATE**

```
class MySerializer(XXXSerializer):
    email = serializers.CharField(default='')
```

I think this would do the job as usual class overriding.

Comment: You are right that is what I want - however, I do not want to directly make the edit inside the library being imported. I want to leave that external_library untouched, and write some codes else where to achieve what you mentioned. Do you know a way to do so?

Comment: @MichaelXu Updated the answer, Hope that's what you are looking for

Comment: I've updated my question to make it clearer about my goal. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think the issue is more complicated - I've ended up just porting the entire module into my project and do the modification on spot... Thanks though!